# There is no menu buttons for GIMP 2.8 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gimp

There is no menu buttons in the top menu bar when opening GIMP 2.8 as seen in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdDqI.png); even if I hover over or make them permanently be displayed. For other applications seem to work, but not for GIMP.
Any idea why?

Comment: You need to have the main window active (the one with the image in it, not the toolbox, not the layer window) to see the menubar. You probably need to hover over the bar at the top of the screen (where it says "GIMP Image Editor").

Comment: Can't reproduce this here... all is as expected with both, single window and multiple window mode, and also with both, Ambiance and Radiance theme. What is your Gimp version?

Comment: @Takkat I'm using Gimp 2.8.16

Comment: It seems that an update fixed it.. all good now. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the update you were talking about.
I'm having the issue after I upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
I'm using Gimp 2.8.16 and I have this problem both in single window and multiple window mode.
The only workaround I found is to logout and then login after the first boot up in the OS.
Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What I did is the following: **System Settings** -> **Appearance** -> **Behavior**-> **Show the menus for a window**: In the Menu bar & **Menus Visibility**: Always display, then I've completely removed GIMP and reinstalled it. And it seems to work from the first login. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. 
I set the menu Bar as you described and I just removed the Gimp GUI setting files from the .gimp2.8 folder for resetting it instead of reinstall the program. (so I was able to keep all the plugins I added to the program)
Then I started the application and everything went well.
After all this I set again the menu bar as it is the default for Ubuntu 16.04 (only visible when the mouse is over it). After a reboot everything was perfect.
Thanks a lot again. :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to hear that! Maybe you can add all this steps in a complete answer to the question for others to find :)

Comment: It worked for me but only after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (Ubuntu in German).

Beside reinstall Gimp and reboot, i had to remove the directory ~/.gimp-2.8 (just after deinstall).

After that, it worked as expected.